# Reference for proof that vertical composition of pseudonatural transformations is a pseudonatural transformation

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Is there a standard reference for the fact that the vertical composition of two pseudonatural transformations between pseudofunctors between bicategories is a pseudonatural transformation? Recall that vertical composition of two pseudonatural transformations between pseudofunctors between bicategories as below

[image]     [image]

[image]

is given by

$$(\Theta'\circ\Theta)_X=\Theta'_X\circ\Theta_X,$$
$$(\Theta'\circ\Theta)_f=\alpha^\mathfrak{D}\circ(\Theta'_f\star1)\circ\alpha^{\mathfrak{D}^{-1}}\circ(1\star\Theta_f)\circ\alpha^\mathfrak{D}$$

as illustrated below for an arrow $f:A\to B\in\mathfrak{C}$

[image]

Is there a standard reference proving that $\Theta'\circ\Theta$ satisfies the coherence diagrams/naturality condition for a pseudonatural transformation? It seems like a pretty ugly chase, and while there's no doubt it'll work out a reference to use as a guide would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see Lemma 4.2.19 of

> **[JY]** Niles Johnson and Donald Yau, *2-Dimensional Categories*, 2021, Oxford University Press [Link](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/2-dimensional-categories-9780198871378?sortField=1&type=listing&facet_narrowbytype_facet=Academic%20Research&lang=en&cc=es#). [[arXiv]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Happy to know this was helpful :) By the way, [Adrian Miranda's master thesis](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/adrian_miranda.pdf) also has careful diagram chases, with quite a bit of overlap with [JY], but also other stuff. For instance, p.62 there is a solution of Exercise 4.7.11 of [JY].